# $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)\cap\mathbb{Q}(\xi_m) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\xi_{\gcd(n,m)})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)\cap\mathbb{Q}(\xi_m) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\xi_{\gcd(n,m)})$ where $\xi_i$ is a primitive $i$th root of unity.

How can I show this? Could you give any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For $E/F$ Galois and $L/F$ then $[EL:L]=[E:E\cap L]$.

For simplicity assume that $E=F(a)$, let $g\in L[x]$ be the $L$-minimal polynomial of $a$, since all the roots of $g$ are in $E$ we get that $g\in E\cap L[x]$ so it is in fact the $E\cap L$-minimal polynomial of $a$ thus of degree $[E:E\cap L]$.

Then use it to find $$[\Bbb{Q}(\xi_n):\Bbb{Q}(\xi_n)\cap \Bbb{Q}(\xi_m)]$$ and compare with $$\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(\gcd(n,m))} = [\Bbb{Q}(\xi_n):\Bbb{Q}(\xi_{\gcd(n,m)}]$$

Comment: That's cool. Thanks